# Why are my flows not connecting?

Tags: noflo

Just starting with noflo, I'm baffled as why I'm not able to get a simple flow working. I started today, installing noflo and core components following the example pages, and the canonical "Hello World" example

```
Read(filesystem/ReadFile) OUT -> IN Display(core/Output)
'package.json' -> IN Read
```

works... so far fine, then I wanted to change it slightly adding "noflo-rss" to the mix, and then changing the example to

```
Read(rss/FetchFeed) OUT -> IN Display(core/Output)
'http://xkcd.com/rss.xml' -> IN Read
```

Running like this

```
$ /node_modules/.bin/noflo-nodejs --graph graphs/rss.fbp --batch --register=false --debug
```

... but no cigar -- there is no output, it just sits there with no output at all

If I stick a `console.log` into the sourcecode of FetchFeed.coffee

```
parser.on 'readable', ->
  while item = @read()
    console.log 'ITEM', item  ## Hack the code here
    out.send item
```

then I do see the output and the content of the RSS feed.

*Question:*  Why does `out.send` in rss/FetchFeed not feed the data to the `core/Output` for it to print?  What dark magic makes the first example work, but not the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running with `--batch` the process will exit when the network has stopped, as determined by a non-zero number of open connections between nodes.
The problem is that rss/FetchFeed does not open a connection on its outport, so the connection count drops to zero and the process exists.

One workaround is to run without --batch. Another one I just submitted as a [pull request](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-rss/pull/61) (needs review).